# C# email validation on length on compex regex part

Tags: .net, regex

I have this regex on c# with escape chars

```
^((?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@)))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$
```

Or this without escaping chars

```
^(?(")(".+?(?<!\\)"@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`{}|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@)).{1.64}(?([)([(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*.)+[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$
```

I want to be able to limit the first part of the email before @ to be of length 64 chars. I have tried with positive look ahead but it did not work.

Comment: I got this from Microsoft, they recomand it :(

Comment: Ok, I see, you just removed too much from the verbatim string literal. What you ask for is adding `(?<=^.{1,64}@)` right after each `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `(?<=^.{1,64}@)` positive lookbehind right after each `@`. It will require 1 to 64 chars from the start of the string before that `@`.

The pattern string will look like

```
 ^((?(")(".+?(?<!\\)"@(?<=^.{1,64}@))|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#$%&'*+/=?^`{}|~\w])*)@(?<=[0-9a-z]@)(?<=^.{1,64}@))))(?(\[)(\[(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%28%3F%28%22%29%28%22.%2B%3F%28%3F%3C!%5C%5C%29%22%40%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.%7B1%2C64%7D%40%29%29%7C%28%28%5B0-9a-z%5D%28%28%5C.%28%3F!%5C.%29%29%7C%5B-!%23%24%25%26%27*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E%60%7B%7D%7C%7E%5Cw%5D%29*%29%40%28%3F%3C%3D%5B0-9a-z%5D%40%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.%7B1%2C64%7D%40%29%29%29%29%28%3F%28%5C%5B%29%28%5C%5B%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%29%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5D%29%7C%28%28%5B0-9a-z%5D%5B-0-9a-z%5D*%5B0-9a-z%5D*%5C.%29%2B%5Ba-z0-9%5D%5B-a-z0-9%5D%7B0%2C22%7D%5Ba-z0-9%5D%29%29%24&i=abc%40ab.com).

Note I moved `(?<=[0-9a-z])` after `@` while adding `@` to the lookaround to only perform the check once the `@` is already matched to streamline internal matching process.

When using the string inside a verbatim string literal, just double the double quotes:

```
var pattern = @"^((?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@(?<=^.{1,64}@))|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#$%&'*+/=?^`{}|~\w])*)@(?<=[0-9a-z]@)(?<=^.{1,64}@))))(?(\[)(\[(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";
```